# I need to retrieve customer balance detail from Quick Books for the desktop

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am not sure the best way to retrieve customer balance detail from Quick Books.  I tried using the TransactionQuery, but it was missing customer payments (see code below).  I also tried using the GeneralDetailReportQuery, but this format is difficult to read directly into SQL since it needs some manipulation.  What is the best way to get customer balance detail for a statement?

TransactionQuery Code:

```
Public Sub BuildCustomerStmtRq(ByRef inputXMLDoc As XmlDocument, ByRef qbXMLMsgsRq As XmlElement)
Dim TransactionQueryRq As XmlElement
TransactionQueryRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("TransactionQueryRq")
qbXMLMsgsRq.AppendChild(TransactionQueryRq)
TransactionQueryRq.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("IncludeRetElement")).InnerText = "TxnDate"
TransactionQueryRq.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("IncludeRetElement")).InnerText = "Amount"
    TransactionQueryRq.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("IncludeRetElement")).InnerText = "Memo"
    TransactionQueryRq.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("IncludeRetElement")).InnerText = "EntityRef"
Dim TransactionAccountFilter As XmlElement
        TransactionAccountFilter = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("TransactionAccountFilter")
        TransactionQueryRq.AppendChild(TransactionAccountFilter)
        TransactionAccountFilter.AppendChild(MakeSimpleElem(inputXMLDoc, "AccountTypeFilter", "AccountsReceivable"))

End Sub

    'Copied this function from Intuit example code
    Private Function MakeSimpleElem(doc As XmlDocument, tagName As String, tagVal As String) As XmlElement
        Dim elem As XmlElement
        elem = doc.CreateElement(tagName)
        elem.InnerText = tagVal
        Return elem
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

CustomerBalanceDetail from the GeneralDetailReport is probably the only request that will give you all of the information.  A CustomerQuery is only going to give you the totals, if that would work for what you are needing.

Comment: Are there any available code samples for converting this back into date, name, amount, memo?

Comment: This SQL is pretty close:                                                                 select
 col1=Rpt.Elm.value('(ColData[1]/@value)','varchar (50)'),
 col2=Rpt.Elm.value('(ColData[2]/@value)','varchar (50)'),
 col3=Rpt.Elm.value('(ColData[3]/@value)','varchar (50)'),
 col4=Rpt.Elm.value('(ColData[4]/@value)','varchar (50)'),
 name=Rpt.Elm.value('(RowData[1]/@value)','varchar (50)')
from @QBResponse.nodes('/QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/GeneralDetailReportQueryRs/ReportRet/ReportData/DataRow') as Rpt(Elm)

Comment: When I specify the columns to return for the CustomerBalanceDetail, it eliminates the first DataRow with the name and beginning balance and replaces it with a TextRow with the name and no beginning balance.  How can I specify the columns while keeping the beginning balance data?